# Large dataframe pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

I am trying to make a pivot table for a Pabdas Dataframe that has more then 30 millions rows.

Here is my dataframe pic:

[image: Here is my dataframe pic]

I am trying the following `pivot_table()` for it:

```
fundos_bd = bd.pivot_table(index='DT_COMPTC', columns='CNPJ_FUNDO', values='VL_QUOTA')
```

It works but it doesn't process all data from the dataframe. Lots of rows on the pivoted table return `None` values.

Here an example of the described:

[image: Here an example of the described]

If I take just the same `CNPJ_FUNDO` (on the picture above) from my dataframe and pivot it it works as it should.

Tried `groupby()` function but it didn't work either.

Comment: Hello friend beep boop, please display your data or make a dict so we can help you better

Comment: First time I put a question here. Where do I display my data? I did put some screenshots from it, since it is a big dataframe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  please follow the guidelines here in providing reproducible example